# Show request's timestamp in Fiddler?

Tags: javascript, fiddler

I received a long Fiddler trace (with a complicated scenario) and need to correlate the requests with application logs.

Unfortunately, while Fiddler displays the requests chronologically, it doesn't display the timestamps of the request. To access that information (which is recorded) I have to right-click each line and look in the pop-up window with the properties. This is very time-consuming when having to comb through hundreds of lines. Looking at the raw capture data is not much better as each request has its own file and I do need the Fiddler interface.

Pedantic note: I'm aware there isn't a single timestamp to show (below are all the timestamps that are recorded). ClientConnected would be fine (or any other, as long as it's the same, that allows me to correlate the logs visually).

Thanks.

```
== TIMING INFO ============
ClientConnected:        10:32:57:8906
ClientDoneRequest:      10:32:57:8906
Gateway Determination:  0ms
DNS Lookup:         0ms
TCP/IP Connect:         0ms
ServerGotRequest:       10:32:57:9062
ServerBeginResponse:    10:32:58:2812
ServerDoneResponse: 10:32:58:2884
ClientBeginResponse:    10:32:58:2900
ClientDoneResponse: 10:32:58:2912
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

**Update**: In current versions of Fiddler, simply right-click the column headers and choose **Customize Columns**. In the dropdown, choose **Session Timers** and choose `ClientBeginRequest` in the dropdown list.

The old way to do this is to use FiddlerScript. Click *Rules* > *Customize Rules*.

Inside the class `Handlers`, add the following script code:

```
public static BindUIColumn("BeginRequestTime", 60)
function BeginRequestTime(oS: Session)
{
    if (oS.Timers != null)
    {
        return oS.Timers.ClientBeginRequest.ToString();     
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Then, simply reload your SAZ file.

Comment: I'm using Fiddler 4.5.1.0. Following the way you told, I can get the **time** info displayed, but don't see the **date** info. How can I also display the date info as well? Thanks.

Comment: @cateyes: The built-in column providers show the DateTime formatted with only the time string. To show the date, use the `BindUIColumn` method and use the overload of `ToString()` that accepts a datetimeformatstring.

Comment: Where can I find the usage/definitions of the overload methods then?

Comment: When you want to find information about .NET APIs, MSDN is where to look. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Didn't know it's .NET stuff, my bad. Thanks :)